# FileVersionInfo and AssemblyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, version-control, version, versioning

Given this snippet from Blah.dll's AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.3.3.3")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.2.2.2")]
```

And then in a separate .exe:

```
var fileInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("/path/to/Blah.dll");
fileInfo.ProductVersion == fileInfo.FileVersion == true;
```

Other SO questions show ProductVersion being "correct", curious if there is something odd about how I'm using it.

Shouldn't ProductVersion be "3.3.3.3" and FileVersion be "2.2.2.2"?  What would cause it to report both properties as AssemblyFileVersion?

Comment: ... and what is the question?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I found the answer originally [here](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/368348-assemblyversion-fileversion).  I'm repeating the details for ease of reference.

There are three 'versions' that can be included in the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.1.1")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("2.2.2.2")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("3.3.3.3")]
```

`AssemblyInformationalVersion` defaults to `AssemblyFileVersion` if it is not specified.  Likewise, `AssemblyInformationalVersion` ***and*** `AssemblyFileVersion` default to `AssemblyVersion` if both are not specified.

In your example, the AssemblyInfo.cs file did not include `AssemblyInformationalVersion`, so it defaults to the value of `AssemblyFileVersion`.  As you will see below, `AssemblyInformationalVersion` maps to the `FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion` property, which explains why the test returns true.

Obviously, there are a couple of frustrating aspects to this.  First, there is no way (that I know of) to set the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` from Visual Studio.  You have to modify the AssemblyInfo.cs file directly to include this attribute.  Second, `AssemblyInformationalVersion` maps to the `FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion` property, which is non-intuitive.  The attribute should more properly be named `AssemblyProductVersion`. And apparently, a *title* is also a *description*, etc.

That said, how do we retrieve these (and related) values in code?  Like this:

> ```
> AssemblyFileVersion          => System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
> AssemblyInformationalVersion => System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion
> AssemblyVersion              => System.Reflection.Assembly.Version
>
> /// others...
> AssemblyTitle                => System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription
> AssemblyDescription          => System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.Comments
> AssemblyProduct              => System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.ProductName
> AssemblyCompany              => System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.CompanyName
> AssemblyCopyright            => System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.LegalCopyright
> AssemblyTrademark            => System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.LegalTrademarks
> ```

In the case of `AssemblyVersion`, use this:

```
string ver = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Comment: I accepted the answer because that is the correct explanation, but I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve Loading (or even ReflectionOnly Loading) the assembly.  But thanks for hunting down at least that!

Comment: If you want to be able to read Assembly version from a DLL without loading or reflection-only-loading, then you can read the meta-data purely as a data source, into an object model using the Microsoft Common Compiler Infrastructure (CCI) library. You'll be interested in the MetaDataReaderHost. Its fast, and doesnt 'CLR load' the DLL in any way - giving the advantage of being able to read meta data from DLLs that are compiled against newer versions of the runtime than your application, thereby future proofing your application.

http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/

Comment: @ecoffey: "System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fullPath)" doesn't load the assembly, and you can call "FileVersion" or "ProductVersion.

Comment: @ecoffey Very ancient now, but pending Matt's approval of my edits, I've updated his list here to more completely show the mapping.

Comment: @user276648: Your comment regarding `ProductVersion` is just not true, this (at least now) retrieves `[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("...")]`.