# Which is better for getting assembly location , GetAssembly().Location or GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

Please suggest which is the best to getting executing assembly location.

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(NUnitTestProject.RGUnitTests)).Location
```

or

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Please suggest which can be better. Can I use `GetEntryAssembly()` also?

Comment: Which assembly do you want to get the location of?

Comment: They do different things, so there is no best one.

Comment: Executing assembly ,I need to get `bin\Debug` path for calculating somthing

Comment: If you need executing assembly, then why consider any other than GetExecutingAssembly() ?

Comment: Things get complicated when you create a library, which is being called inside a web application or service. What is your project type?

Comment: My project type is `NUnit test library` type and i am using path inside the `NUnit` project and get test configuration which is deployed at `bin\debug` when tests starts.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It depends on what you want.

- `Assembly.GetAssembly` returns the assembly where `type` is declared.
- `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` returns the assembly where the **current code** is being executed on.
- `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` returns the **process executable**. Keep in mind that this may not be your executable.

For example, imagine your code is on `myexecutable.exe`.

`trdparty.exe` uses `Assembly.LoadFile` to load your executable and run some code by reflection.

`myexecutable.exe` uses type `MyClass`

but the `trdparty.exe` patches your code to use the new version of `MyClass` located in `Patch.dll`.

So now, if you run your application all by itself, you get this result:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)) -> myexecutable.exe
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() -> myexecutable.exe
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() -> myexecutable.exe
```

but if you have the scenario mentioned above, you get:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)) -> Patch.dll
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() -> myexecutable.exe
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() -> trdparty.exe
```

So as a response, you should use the one that provides the result you want.
The answer may seem obvious that it is `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`, but sometimes it's not. Imagine that you are trying to load the `application.config` file associated with the executable, then the path will most probably be `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` to always get the path of the "process".

As I said, it depends on the scenario and the purpose.

Comment: In my case 'Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()' is null .Rest two are given `dll` path

Comment: documentation says "can return null when a managed assembly has been loaded from an unmanaged application"

Comment: But i am using `C#.net` which is managed application. I dont know if `NUnit` dll is managed or unmanaged.

Comment: is it a web aplication?

Comment: No its a `NUnit` test library project which is created in `C#.net`

Comment: if you say the other 2 are returning your dll.. and if it is what you want.. them you should use `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass))` or its equivalent `typeof(Example).Assembly` because MSDN says `GetExecutingAssembly` as worse performance

Comment: GetEntryAssembly() is null in ASP.NET. It is set in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @Der_Meister your last comment, this is what i am seeing, shouldn't they be the same regardless, its making it confusing as to which one to use

Comment: @Seabizkit I did not test, but I assume that the entry assembly will be set in reverse proxy mode. ASP.NET Core also supports IIS in-process hosting model - I think the entry assembly will be null in that case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#in-process-hosting-model

Comment: For .NET I have a method that works for both desktop and web apps: https://github.com/Saritasa/dotnet-deploy/blob/asp-net/src/DeployDemo.Web/Support/Util.cs

Comment: @Der_Meister The GetEntryAssembly() is null in ASP.NET. because the process executable is not a .net assembly, it is a IIS process, probably w3wp.exe which is a native windows assembly.. in that case one of the other methods should be called..

Comment: @CaldasGSM that makes a little more sense... would be neat to have a proper write up about it.

Answer (score -3):

It seems rather obvious: When you want the executing assembly, use `GetExecutingAssembly`.

Sometimes you don't have one, for example when running as an Office add-in. You could use `Assembly.GetAssembly` instead.