# Read assembly version of class library Project from .netCore web app project

Tags: asp.net-core, semantic-versioning

I have 4 web applications based on .net core. all of them call a business logic layer (class library)

i want my version to get updated on all 4 web applications.

I have tried to make a static class on my business logic layer. and on this class i have a property that gets the version as the following:

```
Assembly.GetEnteryAssembly().GetName().Version
```

i tried to call this static class from one of the applications, sadly it brings the version of the web application instead of the class library version.

I want a code that always brings me the version of class library regardless from where it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(YourClass))`, being `YourClass` any class within desired assembly.

Comment: you gave me a guide at least

i have used Assemply.GetExecutingAssembly() as the class where i get the version from is in the business logic, and GetEnteryAssembly always get the application version from where you have entered the application

Comment: [Have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059748/which-is-better-for-getting-assembly-location-getassembly-location-or-getexe), in some scenarios you may not get what you're looking for using `GetExecutingAssembly()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()`